# Using ref with in 2 forms..?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have 2 forms..

from first form i call 2nd form... in second form i do some calculations and i want to get the result in first form after closing second form.

### First Form Code

```
public partial class XtraForm1 : DevExpress.XtraEditors.XtraForm
{
    String s = "";
    public XtraForm1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void simpleButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        s = textEdit1.Text;
        XtraForm2 x = new XtraForm2(ref s);

        x.ShowDialog();
        MessageBox.Show(s); // Here I want to get the data from 2nd form.
    }
}
```

### 2nd Form Code

```
public partial class XtraForm2 : DevExpress.XtraEditors.XtraForm
{
    string s2 = "";
    public XtraForm2(ref string s1)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        s2 = "hai";
        s1 = s2;
    }

    private void simpleButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // here i do some operations and i want to store it in variable s1 so that i will get the result in 1st form.
        this.Close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a number of things you could do.

But easiest is to create a property on your second form, put the result in there and call it from your first form after the `ShowDialog()` like `MessageBox.Show(x.MyProperty);`

Answer (score 0):

You can use properties, right? Why you want to pass parameters byRef?

```
Button_click(){
    using(var form2 = new Form2())
    {
        form2.Property = initialValue;
        form2.ShowDialog();
        MessageBox.Show(form2.Property);
    }
}
```

Instead of using get set property, `you can pass the value using constructor` and `get the value from property`.

Answer (score 0):

Create a public field/property in 2nd Form.

```
//public property
public string Data { get;set;}

private void simpleButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   Data="Something you want to return back to 1st Form";
   this.Close();
}
```

In 1st Form,

```
private void simpleButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  s = textEdit1.Text;
  XtraForm2 x = new XtraForm2(ref s);

  x.ShowDialog();
  MessageBox.Show(x.Data); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility would be to use a static variable:

```
public static string _form2Data = null;

private void simpleButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)   
{   
    _form2Data = "something";     
    this.Close();   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create class that acts like model and declare all your variable 
and use set to edit data and get to get it.

```
Public class cs1
{
   private int m_id=0;

public int ID
{
    get
    {
        return m_id;
    }
    set
    {
        m_id = value;
    }
}

}
```